# Fastest way of getting most frequent and similar values inside an array?

Tags: c#, sorting, integer, similarity

I have an array of ints in C# and I want to get 5% of the whole array, in the way that the new array includes the most frequent similar values.
For an example, say I have an array with 100 entries that includes 40 siblings of 20 (15 to 25). What I want is to detect the 20 as the most frequent value (including it's siblings) as a new array and then 5 most frequent values inside the new array.
I need to run the code on an ASP.net website and because of that, I need a fast algorithem.
Could anyone help me with this please?

Comment: What will your *real* array size be? How clustered will the data be, and do you know the actual ranges?

Comment: Side note: there is no real causation between  "run the code on an ASP.net website" and "need a fast algorithm"... It often quite opposite - running slow/complicated code on server...

Comment: @JonSkeet The array may be as big as 1024*1024 in size and the ranges are between 0 and 255. In fact the array is a byte array. If it is important, I will change my question to fit that. The cluster may be 10.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov So what one can do if a website should offer graphic services like setting the theme color of a page using the most frequent color inside a picture used inside that page dynamically?

Comment: I don't know. I think the search term you are looking for is "histogram" which should give you starting point for finding right algorithm.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight The question says: "...includes 40 'siblings' of 20 (15 to 25)." and by that, I mean something like this {20, 22, 19, 24, 18}.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build a simple algorithm by grouping the values, ordering by count, and then taking them until you fill the required 5% array, like this:

```
// Build a set of {Value, Count} pairs using LINQ
var counts = data
    .GroupBy(v => v)
    .Select(g => new {
        Value = g => Key
    ,   Count = g.Count()
    }).OrderByDescending(p => p.Count)
    .Take(5);
```

**EDIT :**

> The array may be as big as 1024*1024 in size and the ranges are between 0 and 255

Since the range is very small, you can use counting array instead of a group, like this:

```
int counts = new int[256];
foreach (var b in data) {
    counts[b]++;
}
```

Now you can run the [*Quick Select Algorithm*](http://pine.cs.yale.edu/pinewiki/QuickSelect) to choose the fifth item. Here is [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15396693/335858) that provides a C# implementation of `QuickSelect`.

```
var fifth = QuickSelect(counts, 5);
var res = new List<KeyValuePair<int,int>>();
for (int i = 0 ; i != counts.Length && res.Length != 5 ; i++) {
    if (counts[i] >= fifth) {
        res.Add(new KeyValuePair<int,int>(i, counts[i]));
    }
}
```

You may want to replace the quick select algorithm with the [median-of-medians algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Linear_general_selection_algorithm_-_Median_of_Medians_algorithm), which has the same linear performance, but is not randomized.

Answer (score 2):

```
var numbersByOccurrence = from numbers in yourNumberArrayVariable
                          group numbers by numbers into g
                          select new { Number = g.Key, Count = g.Count() };

var limitedSize = numbersByOccurrence.OrderByDescending(n => n.Count).Take(5);
```

You now have an variable (you can cast as an array or list) of 5 objects with a Number and Count variable you can easily access.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is as good as the selected answer except I personally prefer lambda instead of Linq query.